# Twilio 'RecordingUrl' Not Being Passed to my Parse Cloud Code

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, cloud, twilio, twilio-php

I have some php Twiml that successfully makes calls and records them before firing off some Parse Cloud code to retrieve the RecordingUrl:

```
$response->dial($callee, array(action=>"https://myApp.parseapp.com/handleRecording", 'callerId'=>$callerId, record=>true));
```

My Parse Cloud Code is as follows:

```
// Include Cloud Code module dependencies
var express = require('express'),
    twilio  = require('twilio');

var app = express();
twilio.initialize("ACr245kl2hj54245245324","252k5kjk5j4525234252525252b54v5"); 

app.post('/handleRecording', function(request, response){
         //var recUrl = request.body.RecordingUrl + ".wav";    // This is
         //var recUrl = request.params.RecordingUrl + ".wav";  // always nil
         console.log(request);
         console.log(response);
        });
```

The problems is that there is no response Body, only header. The status code is 200, but it also says success/error was not called. What am I missing here? Am hoping one of the famed Twilio Enthusiasts will come to the rescue, cause I've wasted a day trying to get a silly url. Output is as follows:

Result: success/error was not called
{"domain":null,"_events":null,"_maxListeners":10,"method":"POST","url":"/handleRecording","headers":{"cache-control":"max-age=259200","content-length":"567","content-type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8","host":"myApp.parseapp.com","referer":"https://myAppsTwilioServer.herokuapp.com/twiml.php","user-agent":"TwilioProxy/1.1","version":"HTTP/1.1","x-forwarded-for":"10.252.1.70","x-forwarded-proto":"https","x-twilio-signature":"24958u49843985934579kjkjdf45="},"httpVersion":["HTTP/1.1","1.1"],"connection":{},"originalUrl":"/handleRecording","_parsedUrl":{"protocol":null,"slashes":null,"auth":null,"host":null,"port":null,"hostname":null,"hash":null,"search":null,"query":null,"pathname":"/handleRecording","path":"/handleRecording","href":"/handleRecording"},"query":{},"res":{"domain":null,"_events":null,"_maxListeners":10,"statusCode":200,"headersSent":false,"sendDate":true,"req":{},"viewCallbacks":[],"_hasConnectPatch":true},"_route_index":0,"route":{"pat... (truncated)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

When [Twilio sends data through a POST request](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/twilio_request), it does it as form encoded url parameters. You need to parse those out from the raw body.

The usual way to do this is by installing express's [body-parser](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser) module via npm, and then using it to parse incoming request bodies like so:

```
var express = require('express'),
    bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
    twilio  = require('twilio');

var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
twilio.initialize("{{ AccountSid }}","{{ AuthToken }}"); 

app.post('/handleRecording', function(request, response){
         //var recUrl = request.body.RecordingUrl + ".wav";    // This is
         //var recUrl = request.params.RecordingUrl + ".wav";  // always nil
         console.log(request);
         console.log(response);
        });
```

Let me know if that helps at all.